# CSS: 100% Height Issues

Tags: css, height, html

I know that there have been a number of posts regarding the height:100% declaration in CSS, yet none of them have resolved the issue I'm struggling with.

In a nutshell, this is what I'm facing: http://cornerstonearts.hostasaurus.com/about/cornerstone_history

All of the height settings for the elements and container divs – html, body, #static-content, #sidebar, #static-maincontent – are 100%:

```
html {
height: 100%;
}

body {
background-color:#d5af6a;
margin:0;
height: 100%;
}

#static-content {
width:960px;
background-color:#FFF;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: auto;
position: relative;
height: 100%;
overflow-y: visible;
}

#sidebar {
width:320px;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
height: 100%;
overflow-y: visible;
}

#static-maincontent {
width:600px;
position: absolute;
left: 340px;
top: 0px;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-color: #AC740C;
height: 100%;
overflow-y: visible;
}
```

I read a couple of posts that suggest the problem might be the use of absolute positioning. I didn't see how that could be the cause. If a DIV is absolutely positioned, it should still expand to accommodate its contents.

Nevertheless, using Firebug, I changed all of the elements to be positioned relatively and had the sidebar and main columns float left. I still had the same problem.

This is one of those things that I'm sure must have a simple solution that I'm just not seeing. After all, how hard can it be to have a page element expand to 100% of the height of its container?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: W3 validator shows 14 errors on that page.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed those. One of those is because I used the same DIV ID twice, but the others are all part of the Facebook "Like Box," which is generated by FB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An element positioned absolute doesn't affect the wrapping elements in any way. So the height of your div#static-maincontent doesn't really translate to div#static-content... it just floats above all other elements.

- Remove all position:absolute
- give div#sidebar a float:left
- give div#static-maincontent a float:right
- add something like <div style="clear:both;"> after div#static-maincontent and INSIDE div#static-content
- remove height: 100% from div#static-content

This should work (at least with firebug).

Comment: It totally worked! I has to add a few margin settings to reposition everything, but that did the trick. Thanks so much!

Comment: FYI, removing the height: 100% from div#static-content breaks the layout on pages with shorter articles (example: http://cornerstonearts.hostasaurus.com/news/news_item_4). 

If you turn it off, the white background stops at the end of the content, instead of continuing down to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

change the following in your css ( tested it using firebug - works ) --

```
#static-content {
width: 960px;
background-color: white;
margin:0 auto;
position: relative;
height: auto;
overflow: hidden;
}
#sidebar {
width: 320px;
height: 100%;
overflow-y: visible;
float: left;
}
#static-maincontent {
width: 600px;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom-color: #AC740C;
overflow-y: visible;
height: 100%;
float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will actually solve your problem. http://jsfiddle.net/AVRMy/1/

I got rid of:

```
overflow-y: visible;
height: 100%;
```

from all your CSS. Then added:

```
        <div style="clear: both; width: 100%;"></div>
```

right after the closing tag for the div `static-maincontent`.